# GitLab 6.0 Remove User From Group

Tags: permissions, gitlab

I just updated to  GitLab version 6.0, and I don't see any option to remove a user from a group once they have been added.

To be clear, let's say you have two GitLab user accounts with the first name "Steve".  So you're trying to add "Steve J." to a particular group, but you accidentally added "Steve R." instead.  Steve R. shouldn't have access to this group.

So how do you get Steve R. out of the group?

I've tried everything I can think of short of going directly to the database and modifying it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 6.0.2 there's a panel for removing and modifying a user's group permission:

Enter a group's dashboard, in the superior menu there's a "Members" link. That should be it.

URL is like http://{gitlab-host}/groups/{group-name}/members

Comment: Good to know, +1, even though the issue I mentioned in my own answer isn't solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the [issue 5277](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5277) talks about:

> They couldn't do it in the Admin Area.
>   They couldn't do it in the Members area of the Group.
>
> **Said admin must go to "`My Account`", click on `Groups`, and then "`Leave Group`"**.

May be you can apply that for user, going the user account page.

The [OP C Overton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864555/c-overton) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281906/gitlab-6-0-remove-user-from-group/19282262?noredirect=1#comment28557361_19282262):

> I checked and this only works for removing myself from a group. I still can't remove another user from a group, even though I'm an admin.
>   **The alternative is to contact the user and ask them to remove themselves from the group, but this isn't really practical**.

That should complete the requirements for isse 5277.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I checked and this only works for removing myself from a group.  I still can't remove another user from a group, even though I'm an admin.  As an admin, I should be able to remove users from groups.  I guess the alternative is to contact the user and ask them to remove themselves from the group, but this isn't really practical.

Comment: @COverton I have included your comment in the answer, because I fear that the "alternative" you describe is the only possibility to remove a user (for now).